# SharePoint 2013: April-2017 CU Patch Update Mismatch

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, cumulative-update, patching, build-number

Recently, I have updated `April-2017 CU (KB3178730)` on SharePoint Server 2013.

- Post patching configuration DB version is: `15.0.4927.1000`,
- However when I see articles(Todd blog), should get configuration DB version: `15.0.4919.1003`.

**P.S.** Before patching config DB version was:`15.0.4841.1000` (July-2016 CU).

Comment: What version numbers are reported in your test environments?

Comment: Thank you! Can you suggest me now, what I can do best way without effect share point farm?

Comment: Post patching configuration DB version is: 15.0.4927.1000(April-2017 CU),  Before patching config DB version was:15.0.4841.1000(July-2016 CU).

Comment: Hi @Kishore sorry, I can't get it! 
 what do you mean with the best way in "what I can do the best way without effect share point farm" ! Do you mean the best way to patching or checking the build number? anyway check my article at https://blog.devoworx.net/2014/11/30/find-latest-cumulative-update-installed-in-sharepoint-farm/ it answers all these questions, also it's mentioned in my below answer.

Comment: can I uninstall the April-2017 CU now?

Comment: noway  you can't rollback your CU

Comment: Do you checked the Products and Patches build numbers that already installed on the farm as I mentioned in my answer! what's the mentioned Build number

Comment: When I click 'Check product and patch installation status' , I am able to see perfectly CU # KB3178730 and version no # 15.0.4919.1003. Kindly suggest.

Comment: 15.0.4919.1003 is the correct build number as mentioned in KB and TODD blog, and that mean you have patched your farm to April-2017 CU successfully,

Comment: Do you have another question?!  If no Please, don't forget to mark the below answer as accepted answer to help future visitors.

Comment: @Kishore Don't forget to mark the correct answer as the accepted one to be useful for future visitors. Thank You! https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/tour

Answer (score 5):

Yes you are right, the build number for April 2017 CU is `15.0.4919.1003`

But I advise you to don't trust the build number in **Manage Servers in Farm**, it often gives you a wrong indication about installed fixes.

[image]

Stefan Goßner discussed the reason in details at [SharePoint patching demystified](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/stefan_gossner/2014/08/18/sharepoint-patching-demystified/) I quoted some

> One reason might be that you looked at the KB article for SharePoint
>   server and not the one for SharePoint Foundation. These two components
>   might have slightly different version number – e.g. the SharePoint
>   server package might have been created a couple of days later than the
>   SharePoint Foundation package. As the version number on the "Manager
>   Servers in this farm" page in the Central Admin only shows details for
>   the SharePoint Foundation component you cannot expect to see the
>   version number listed in the SharePoint server KB article.
>
> But even when looking at the SharePoint Foundation KB article there
>   are rare cases that the patch level listed in the central
>   administration is lower than the version number in the KB article. The
>   reason for this is that different fixes are added to the CU at
>   different times. Some fixes modify DLLs of the components other just
>   CSS files or JavaScript files. Most of the fixes affect the
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.dll as this is the core component of the
>   SharePoint Foundation component – so its version number usually has
>   the highest version number in the package. But not always! It might be
>   that the last fix being added to the package is a different file. If
>   this is the case, then the version number in the KB article might
>   reflect the version of this other file. If this file is a DLL you can
>   verify this in explorer. But if this file is just a CSS file or a
>   Javascript file or any other file which does not carry version
>   information then you might not be able to identify the file which
>   defines the version number in the KB article.

**To check Get the Products and Patches build numbers that already installed on the farm.**

[image]

Check the install status and version columns for all installed Products/Patches.

[image]

Also, check other alternative ways to [Find Farm Patch Level/ build number](https://blog.devoworx.net/2014/11/30/find-latest-cumulative-update-installed-in-sharepoint-farm/)